# Не запускается pip

Tags: python, pip

установил py charm комьюнити 2023. пытаюсь добавить библеотеку pygame оно говорит:

```
Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие 
и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pip install pygame
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

помогите!

Comment: Папка venv есть в структуре проекта?

Comment: В смысле "не совсем"? Такая ошибка возникает ровно из-за того, что pip не прописан в переменных окружения системы (точнее, не прописана папка, где он находится). Проблема не с pycharm и не с pygame.